# How to setup instagram business account webhooks?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, instagram, instagram-api

I am new to FB APIs. I want to subscribe to Instagram business accounts and receive mentions in comments, captions, or stories webhooks.
I am following the following docs: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/guides/webhooks/#install-app
The problem is I am able to subscribe to Facebook page fields like mention, feed, etc. using POST /{fb-page-id}/subscribed_apps?subscribed_fields=mention&access_token={fb-page-access-token}. But I am not able to subscribe to my Instagram business account.
The given syntax in FB docs doesn't works:

```
  ?access_token={access-token}
  &fields={fields}
```

I can't put Instagram fields like mentions, comments in the above code it raises errors as well as when I replace the fb-page-id with the id of the Instagram account I get `Unsupported post request`.

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong here?